# Cover SSN with ###

Tags: sql

I want to store secure info in a database including addresses, SSN, and Phone numbers etc. I would like to be able to see the last 4 of the social and phone number and such. Can SQL perform this correctly and securely?

Comment: @Zanyo's answer is pretty close.  Really though, you should rethink storing sensitive stuff like SSN's in your database.  If you must, you must, encrypt the column and make it secure all the way through the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

No. Sql isn't meant for formatting data, only storing and retrieving it. What you should do instead is implement a program that will retrieve data from that database, and then format it.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done anything like it before, but I think I would store the sensitive information in an encrypted format, and then the last 4 numbers in a new column for each in plain text.